# Align data from database in text area

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I display some database data in a text area, but I want to align this data like in mail box. How do I align the text area data? Please help me.

My source code is here:

```
    <h3>Feedback Mail</h3>
 TO

    <%:Html.DropDownList("to", ViewData["EmailID"] as SelectList)%> 
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Process", FormMethod.Post))
   {%>

<table  border="0">

     ![enter image description here][1]<tr><td>  Cc</td>
  <td style="width: 470px"> <input type ="text"  name="cc" id="Cc" style="width: 470px" /><br /></td></tr>
<tr>  <td>  BCc</td>
   <td style="width: 470px">  <input type ="text"  name="bcc" id="BCc" style="width: 470px"/><br /></td></tr>
  <tr>  <td>  Subject</td>
      <td style="width: 470px"> <input type ="text"  name="subject" id="Subject"style="width: 470px" /><br /></td></tr>

   <tr><td> Body</td></tr>

  </table>
       <textarea rows="15" cols="30" id="body" name="body"  style="width: 548px"  >



  Qualification: <%:Model.Candidate.Qualification %>
   Total Experience:<%:Model.Candidate.Experience %>
   Company:<%:Model.Candidate.Company.CompanyName %>
   Current CTC:<%:Model.Candidate.CurrentCTC %>
   Expected CTC:<%:Model.Candidate.ExpectedCTC %>
   Notice Period:<%:Model.Candidate.NoticePeriod %>
  <%:Model.Recruiter.Signature %>

       </textarea>
       <%-- <TextArea  name="value" id="body" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="55" Rows="10"/><br /></td></tr>--%>
     <input type ="submit" name="Sendmail" id="Send" value="Send"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use to align my textarea using CSS. And it works fine.

Inside your view, you may call your css file.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And then design your textarea.

```
textarea#body
{
    width: 750px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following code:

```
<textarea rows="15" cols="30" id="body" name="body" style="width: 548px; text-align:left;" />
```